# Making a class for a class, "reached end of file while parsing"

Tags: java

I am designing a class with methods that directly return the color, calculate and directly return the circumference, and calculate and directly return the area.

```
public class Circle 
{
private double radius;
private double circumference;
private int color;
public double area;

public Circle() {
    radius = 0;
}
public Circle(double radius) {
    my.radius = radius;
}
public double getCircle () {
    return color;
}
public double getArea() {
    return area;
}
public void setCircumference(double circumference) {
    circumference = 2 * Math.pi * radius;
}
public void setArea(double area) {
    area = radius * radius * Math.Pi;
}
public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
}
public String toString() {
return "the radius circumference the circle is: 
" + circumference + ", and the area is : " + area
+ "The color is " + color;
}
```

I'm getting a "reached end of file while parsing" error

Comment: Proper indentation would to make the problem a bit more obvious.

Comment: Just as an aside, I don't think your class needs to store the radius, the circumference AND the area.  It might work better if you just store the radius; and calculate the other two in the respective getters.  Currently, your setCircumference and setArea methods do absolutely nothing.

Comment: hmm yes i see that now :/.

Answer (score 2):

Your class is missing a final brace to close the opening brace that immediately follows `public class Circle`